# nothing display in the second view in MVC c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

In my web site I'm getting data from xml in first controller action method and display as dropdown (html select and option).When a user selects an item in first dropdown, selected item sent to the next view's controller as a parameter using jquery `$.post`. I have keep breakpoints and see what is going on. Data trasfer is success until second view . But display nothing. I have attached screenshot of my break points and codes.

This is my controllers.

```
public ActionResult First()
{
    //get the location data
    var Loc = getData("Location", "", "", "");
    List<FirstData> Ilc = new List<FirstData>();
    foreach(var val in Loc)
    {
       Ilc.Add(new Firstdata
       {
            Destination = val
       });
     }
     ViewBag.Loc = Ilc;
     return View();
}
```

this is how I pass data from first view to second action controller method

```
<script type:"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#chk a").addCIass("btn btn-default");
        $("#chk a").click(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Check","Cruise")';
            $.post(url, { LocNane: $("#desti").val() }, function (data) {
                //alert("succes");
            });
         });
     });
</script>
```

this is how my second controller gets pass data[I made a breakpoint here]

```
public ActionResult Check(string LocName)
{
    string d = LocNane;
    var Nan = getData('Location',"Name",d,"");
    List<Seconddata> nf = new List<Seconddata>();
    foreach (var val in Nam)
    {
        nf.Add(new Seconddata
        {
            Naneof = val
        });
    }
    ViewBag.Nn = nf;
 }
```

and this is my second view and display data in break point

```
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach( var item in @VieuBag.Nm)
        {
            <h3>one</h3>
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

I put "@item.Nameof" inside the header tags , but it didn't work. so just to chek I put one. after go through the loop nothing display.what's the  wrong.please help me with this.

Comment: Is ti possible to write the code, instead of just giving it to screenshots?

Comment: I did my code in windows machine and now I am posting it to stack overflow using my mac. so that is why I used screeenshots

Comment: Do you using `<h3>@item.Nameof</h3>`?

Comment: Where are you appending the returned partial view in page?

Comment: I dont do any appending and I don't know. I'm new to MVC.

Comment: Yes I did it @neiesc

Comment: @anu I put some effort to convert the screenshots to code.

Comment: Do you need for two 'view' it?
this could be done all in jquery.

Comment: Exemple: https://jsfiddle.net/ffbjugL7/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the success handler of $.post does not append/insert the returned html in any element. You can do something like this in success handler where divId is element Id in page where you want to show the returned html.

```
$("#divId").append(data);
```